# Use exotic font-styles in AS3 styleSheet with CS5 new font embedding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, embedded-fonts

I have some dynamic swf that used to retrieve its dynamic text values from an external .xml & style values from an external .css.

Since FlashCS5 and its new font embedding technique, i can't find how to use exotic style anymore. Like for the font-family "HelveticaNeue LT Std", I want to use the style "45 Light" or "65 Medium", "85 Heavy"...

But in my css, it seems i only have "font-family" support. And font-weight is either normal/bold & font-style is normal/italic.

Is there a way to name my fonts like "HelveticaNeue45Light" & use this in my external css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed each font style as an individual font.  You can then choose the font via CSS:

```
font-family: HelveticaNeue LT Std 45 Light;
```

Use the screen name of your embedded font - you can find out the exact name by opening the properties window for the font symbol in your library.

Comment: In fact in my case it is "HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt". The key is to get exact font name from property window. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I have found the above method to not always work. To wit, I am embedding 'Helvetica Neue LT Std 55 Roman' in CS5 on a Windows 7 machine. In the font viewing dialog, the following is shown:

```
Font Name: Helvetica Neue LT Std 55 Roman
Vendor ID: ADBE
Copyright © 1988, 1990, 1993, 2002 Adobe Systems Incorporated.  All Rights Reserved.
http://www.adobe.com/type/legal.html
```

Using that Font Name in the css failed. To get the Flash values of the font, I used the following:

```
var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
for (var i:int = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) 
{
    var font:Font = (fonts[i] as Font)
    trace(font.fontName, ",", font.fontStyle, ",", font.fontType)
}
```

font.fontName is what will be the font-family in your css, and font.fontStyle will be either the font-weight or font-style depending.

For the curious, the shown values for me were: "HelveticaNeueLT Std, regular, embedded"